# How to mock a method that returns void but modifies the reference type passed in with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have an `Interface`

```
public interface IRequester
{
    void Check(Check check);
}
```

I want to mock this using `Moq` which is obviously easy. The issue I have is that I want the `Check` passed in to be modified (as it is a reference) after the mocked call. As you can see `Check` is just a simple POCO.

```
public class Check
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

Ideally I want to change the value of the `Status` property on the `Check` passed in.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `Callback` method. I think it will be something like:

```
yourMock.Setup(x => x.Check(It.IsAny<Check>()))
    .Callback((Check c) => { c.Status = 1234567; });
```

You can leave out the braces `{ }` and the first semicolon `;` if you only need one assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Think you can use the ref keyword to get the thing you want:

> The ref method parameter keyword on a method parameter causes a method
>   to refer to the same variable that was passed into the method. Any
>   changes made to the parameter in the method will be reflected in that
>   variable when control passes back to the calling method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7(v=vs.71).aspx